# Unable to install composer globally on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: laravel, composer-php, macos-catalina

I want to install composer for laravel development on my latest version of mac OS. I followed all the step by step instructions to install composer on the website and it installed `composer.phar`. So I have to move to `/usr/local/bin/composer` for it to work.

I ran the usual command:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

and it gave an error saying `/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory`

I even added a `sudo` command in front to see if it works and received the same error. I looked up other solution telling me to make a new directory there, but it wouldn't let me do so and gave me a `permission denied` error.

Comment: Check if you have already /usr folder? some Mac os versions doesn't have this folder

Comment: I managed to get it work by creating a bin folder and moving composer to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should create the directory manually before proceeding:

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`

then

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: try with sudo and check

Comment: I created manually so it's working now but when I try to install laravel via composer, it gives this: `  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].`

Comment: It's need zip extension, what is your PHP version? get it by php -v

Comment: PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Dec 13 2019 19:21:21) ( NTS )

Answer (score 0):

For solving your second problem
It needs zip extension,

Check your PHP version first

```
php -v
```

If for instance PHP version is 7.2, then try below command (use your PHP version)

```
brew update
brew install php@7.2
brew link php@7.2
```

Comment: I managed to install the laravel installer but when I want to create a new laravel project, it says laravel command not recognized. why?